# Call javascript function after script is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html page where I am appending html at dynamically through a javascript like below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myapp/htmlCode"></script>
```

I want to call a js function e.g. loadedContent(); once the above script adds dynamic html.

Can someone help me how I can do that?

Answer (score 179, accepted):

you can achieve this without using head.js javascript.

```
function loadScript( url, callback ) {
  var script = document.createElement( "script" )
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  if(script.readyState) {  // only required for IE <9
    script.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if ( script.readyState === "loaded" || script.readyState === "complete" ) {
        script.onreadystatechange = null;
        callback();
      }
    };
  } else {  //Others
    script.onload = function() {
      callback();
    };
  }

  script.src = url;
  document.getElementsByTagName( "head" )[0].appendChild( script );
}


// call the function...
loadScript(pathtoscript, function() {
  alert('script ready!'); 
});
```

Comment: FYI: `onload` is ok for IE versions 9 and later - so just setting `onload` is probably ok for most people now

Comment: Note `onload` will start the callback the minute the script "LOADS" not when its actually finished execution, which is disappointing

Comment: @MaDude Can you refer to any documentation regarding that?

Comment: The `onload` handler couldn't possibly be called when the script hasn't finished execution, because Javascript is single threaded. This means the `onload` handler could only be called either BEFORE the script start's execution or AFTER it has finished execution. I personally have never seen the former case to occur...EVER. If anyone knows about a reproducible case where the `onload` handler can be called BEFORE the script starts executing, please tell us.

Comment: A simple extension to load an array of scripts:

```function loadScripts (urls, callback) {var counter = 0
  for (var i=0; i<urls.length; i++) {
    loadScript(urls[i], function () {
      if (++counter === urls.length) {
        callback()
      }
    })
  }
}```

Answer (score 38):

If you're reading this post in 2021, probably you're more used to Promises. A more modern approach is preferable if either all your target browsers support ES6 or you are using a polyfill.

This solution works like *@JaykeshPatel* answer, but it's based on `Promise`s:

```
// definition
function loadScript(scriptUrl) {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = scriptUrl;
  document.body.appendChild(script);
  
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    script.onload = function() {
      res();
    }
    script.onerror = function () {
      rej();
    }
  });
}

// use
loadScript('http://your-cdn/jquery.js')
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Script loaded!');
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.error('Script loading failed! Handle this error');
  });
```

You can pass some contextual variables in arguments of the `res` callback, or if your library imported some global symbol, you can reference it there.

For example, since jQuery introduces the `$` global symbol, you can call `res($)` and create a local scope for it (perfect if you are using TypeScript and you don't want to declare a module variable in each file, in this way you can write `const $ = await loadScript(..)`).

If you don't mean to pass any argument, you can just shorten your code like this:

```
script.onload = res;
script.onerror = rej;
```

Comment: `script.onLoad = res;` // simplify

Comment: @Kunukn there is also a shorter one `return new Promise(res => script.onload = res)`. But assigning a function to `onload` can be easier to read and allows you to pass an argument on resolve

Answer (score 37):

I had the same problem...
My solution (without jQuery) :

```
<script onload="loadedContent();" src ="/myapp/myCode.js"  ></script>
```

Comment: Please note: This will not be compatible with strict CSPs.

Comment: @Bradley are you sure? I guess that addig the `nonce="${nonce}"` should make it work (untested guess).

Comment: @guettli Nope, unfortunately you can't nonce an inline event-handler. Only element contents are "nonceable", so execution would fail if you tried using the OPs attribute with a strict CSP.

Answer (score 13):

try something like this

```
var script = document.createElement('script');

if(script.readyState) {  //IE
script.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if ( script.readyState === "loaded" || script.readyState === "complete" ) {
    script.onreadystatechange = null;
    alert(jQuery);
  }
};
 } else{//others
script.onload = function() {
  alert(jQuery); 
}
}
script.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"
document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 4):

actually you could just put the `loadedContent()` as the last line of the script you're loading
(which is kind of the concept behind JSONP)

Comment: what if it's not your script?

Answer (score 4):

My answer is an extension of the [Jaykesh Patel answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14644704/162049). I've implemented this code in order to load **multiple javascript**. Hope this helps someone:

```
// RECURSIVE LOAD SCRIPTS
function load_scripts( urls, final_callback, index=0 )
{
    if( typeof urls[index+1] === "undefined" )
    {
        load_script( urls[index], final_callback );
    }
    else
    {
        load_script( urls[index], function() {
            load_scripts( urls, final_callback, index+1 );
        } );
    }
}

// LOAD SCRIPT
function load_script( url, callback )
{
    var script = document.createElement( "script" );
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    if(script.readyState) // IE
    {
        script.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if ( script.readyState === "loaded" || script.readyState === "complete" )
            {
                script.onreadystatechange = null;
                callback();
            }
        };
    }
    else // Others
    {  
        script.onload = function() { callback(); };
    }
    script.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName( "head" )[0].appendChild( script );
    debug("javascript included: "+url);
}

// EXAMPLE  
var main = function()
{
    console.log("main function executed");
}
var js = [ "path/to/script-1", "path/to/script-2", "path/to/script-3" ];
load_scripts( js, main );
```

Answer (score 1):

This is all you need

```
await new Promise((resolve) => {
    let script = document.createElement("script");

    script.onload = () => {
        resolve();
    };

    script.src = "https://example.net/app.js";

    document.head.appendChild(script);
});
```

Answer (score -3):

```
  $.getScript("your script",function () {
      "your action";
  });
```