# JavaScript to run after page load

Tags: javascript, html

I want my JavaScript to load after page is loaded but now it iss loading before the the page is loaded.

How can I fix it.

```
<body>
    <h1>My Website</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron"">
            <h1>Let's Learn Javascript</h1>
            <p class="lead">...cause Javascript ROCKS.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/arrays.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/loops.js"></script>
 </body>
```

Comment: where is your javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737031/loading-scripts-after-page-load

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading scripts after page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737031/loading-scripts-after-page-load)

Comment: use "defer" attribute in your script tags

Answer (score 0):

You can use defer keyword to load javascript async after full page loads

```html
<body>
    <h1>My Website</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron"">
            <h1>Let's Learn Javascript</h1>
            <p class="lead">...cause Javascript ROCKS.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="scripts/main.js" defer></script>
    <script src="scripts/arrays.js" defer></script>
    <script src="scripts/loops.js" defer></script>
 </body>
```

Comment: i used the defer attribute still the js is popping up before the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a onload attribute to your code inside the body.

```
<body onload="script();">
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you use "script defer" since your scripts are external. For more information and understanding, kindly follow this link: [HTML Attribute - Script Defer](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp)