# Adding and Loading Javascript to a Browser via Javascript without reloading

Tags: javascript, eclipse-rap

I have a SWT Browser in an Eclipse RAP Application, where i load something on my local server and display that html.

the url looks something like this:
"http://localhost:port/......./myhtml.html"

I want to add script sources into my html without reloading the page. Currently i am doing this with a Javascript which i execute in the Browser.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('src', 'SOMESOURCE');
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

This does work that i end up having the script tags correctly added to the HTML DOM, however it does not load the references, so i can't access anything defined in these script references. But calling something like

```
window.top.location.reload(false)
```

doesnt work either because this reloads the HTML and therefor removing my inital added script tags.

The main problem here is that i am very restricted because of the tecnologies we are using here, so i am only able to execute javascript queries in my browser.

PS:
For testing you just can open any Browser like Chrome and Firefox, open its Developer Toolkit and type that script into the console. The website doesn't matter.

Comment: This should work though... Are you waiting for the script to finish loading? Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7719185/2232127

Comment: @JensV i did add a onload function with a alert for testing, however nothing occurs, thats why i think that the script element although it is added, it's reference is not loaded

Comment: @JensV I think the Problem here is that i add the script tag after the page is loaded but i have no other option

Comment: did you checked this method https://stackoverflow.com/a/19737116/4246826

Comment: @JensV it was not quite the same problem as in the other bug however another answer in the bug solved it for me ... using a promise object it does load the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @JensV for helping me.

The Problem was although i added my script it didnt load its content. So what i was as described in the question.

However as mentioned from @JensV in the Bug

[load scripts asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718935/load-scripts-asynchronously/7719185#7719185)

it is described to use a Promise object this would handle the load and error events.

```
function loadScript(src) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var s;
        s = document.createElement('script');
        s.src = src;
        s.onload = resolve;
        s.onerror = reject;
        document.head.appendChild(s);
    });
}
```

So what i did was first execute that Javascript and therefor adding this function, and then just execute it with the desired source.

Thanks for @JensV again, you might wanna flag this as duplicate, however i think my problem was a bit different then that.