# How to load a js file after loading html?

Tags: javascript

After i load this :

```
$('#buy-div').load('../buyBar/buyBar.html',function() {
 //do some things here
 });
```

I would like to include this :

```
<script src="../buyBar/BuyBar.js"></script> //access some html that does not exist
```

Beacuse in this `js` i am looking for some `html` that does not exist only after the `.load` function is done. (such as `getElementById` or `$('input').keyup(function() {` that happens before the `.load` was finished.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19737031/5463213) may help!

Comment: Just because the elements don’t exist yet, does not mean you have to load the script itself only after they do … Wrap that part of the functionality into a _function_, that you can then call in the load method callback.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figure out i can do it by loading it when `.load` is done :

```
     let script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = "../buyBar/Pay.js";
      document.body.append(script);
```

This works but i am not sure is the best solution.

Comment: check this out:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737031/loading-scripts-after-page-load

Answer (score 1):

Just put the code that you want to run after the html is loaded in a function. Then call that function in the callback function of the `.load('../buyBar/buyBar.html')`

Assume "../buyBar/BuyBar.js" originally contains

```
document.getElementByID("#someElement").innerHTML = "...";
```

You can change it to

```
function someFunction(){document.getElementByID("#someElement").innerHTML = "...";}
```

Now just put `<script src="../buyBar/BuyBar.js"></script>` in the `<head>` as usual. Then do this:

```
$('#buy-div').load('../buyBar/buyBar.html',function() {
    someFunction();
    //do other stuff   
});
```