# not able to run javascript file added dynamically in head tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, performance, load

The callscripts code is below(the second script in head tag). This script(callscripts) has other code to add JS script dynamically in head file, which is not working.

So basically whenever I click an navbar item particular javascript should run(WHICH IS NOT HAPPENING), so that load time is reduced.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".navbar-nav").on('click', '.nav-item', function(ev1) {
    console.log("workingtech");
    console.log(ev1.target);
    if ($(ev1.target).is("#techpagelink")) { //If this target is clicked the below script should be added to head and be executed. 

      var $techscript = $("<script>").attr({
        "type": 'text/javascript',
        src: '/js/flikfeedtech.js'
      });
      $('head').prepend($techscript);
    } else if ($(ev1.target).is("#politicspagelink")) { //If this target is clicked the below script should be added to head and be executed.

      var $politicsscript = $("<script>").attr({
        "type": 'text/javascript',
        src: '/js/flikfeedpoliticsjs.js'
      });
      $('head').prepend($politicsscript);
    } else if ($(ev1.target).is("#movtvpagelink")) { //If this target is clicked the below script should be added to head and be executed.

      var $moviesscript = $("<script>").attr({
        "type": 'text/javascript',
        src: '/js/flikfeedmoviesjs.js'
      });

      $('head').prepend($moviesscript);
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script async type="text/javascript" src="/js/flikfeedjs.js"></script>

<!--  this script(callscripts) has other code to add JS script dynamically in head file, which is not working. -->

<script async type="text/javascript" src="/js/callscripts.js"></script> 


<body>
  <div class="navbar-nav">
    <a href="#foryoupage" class="nav-item nav-link active" id="#foryoupagelink">For You</a>
    <div></div>
    <a href="#techpage" class="nav-item nav-link hello " id="#techpagelink">Technology</a>
    <div></div>
    <a href="#politicspage" class="nav-item nav-link hello" id="#politicspagelink">Politics</a>
    <div></div>
    <a href="#movtvpage" class="nav-item nav-link hello" id="#movtvpagelink">Movies/Tv shows</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

flikfeedpoliticsjs.js code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.asianage.com/rss_feed/?subsectionId=105",
    datatype: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
      //console.log(xml);
      $(xml).find('item').each(function(i, j) {
        title = $(j).find('title').text();
        link = $(j).find('link').text();
        description = $(j).find('description').text();
        thumbnail = "/images/asianagethumb.jpg";
        newsname = "The Asian Age";
        logo = "https://www.asianage.com/images/logo.png";
        articlestech(i, title, description, link, thumbnail, newsname, logo);

      });
    }
  });

  function articlestech(i, title, description, link, thumbnail, newsname, logo) {
    var $divitem = $("<div>").attr('class', 'item grid-group-item col-xs-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12');
    /* console.log("news18");
     console.log(thumbnail);
     console.log(typeof(thumbnail)); */
    var $divthumb = $("<div>").attr({
        "class": 'thumbnail card',
        style: 'border: 1px solid transparent'
      }),
      $divcardheader = $("<div>").attr({
        "class": 'card-header bg-transparent d-flex justify-content-start',
        style: 'border: 1px solid transparent'
      }),
      $divp21 = $("<div>").attr('class', 'p-2'),

      $imgthumb = $("<img>").attr({
        "class": 'img-thumbnail ',
        'style': 'align-content: center',
        'src': logo,
        'width': "35",
        'height': "35"
      }),
      $divp22 = $("<div>").attr('class', 'p-2'),
      $pnewsname = $("<p>").text(newsname),
      $divmrauto = $("<div>").attr('class', 'mr-auto p-2'),
      $button = $("<button>").attr({
        id: "tnie",
        class: "follow-button"
      }).text("+Follow"),

      $divimg = $("<div>").attr('class', 'img-event');

    if (newsname == "CineJosh") {
      var $imggrp = $("<img>").attr({
        "class": 'group list-group-image img-fluid img-thumbnail',
        src: thumbnail,
        width: "254",
        height: "212"
      });
    } else {
      var $imggrp = $("<img>").attr({
        "class": 'group list-group-image img-fluid img-thumbnail',
        src: thumbnail
      });
    }

    var $divcaption = $("<div>").attr('class', 'caption card-body'),
      $headcard = $("<h4>").text(title).attr('class', 'group card-title inner list-group-item-heading'),
      $paracard = $("<p>").attr('class', 'group inner list-group-item-text').text(description);

    var $divflex = $("<div>").attr('class', 'd-flex justify-content-end'),
      $divtime = $("<div>").attr({
        "class": 'mr-auto p-2',
        'id': 'time'
      }),
      $small = $("<small>").attr('class', 'text-muted').text('3 mins ago'),
      $divsvg = $("<div>").attr({
        'class': 'p-2',
        'id': 'svgs'
      }),


      $svgcapa_1 = makeSVG('svg', {
        'version': '1.1',
        'id': "Capa_1",
        'xmlns:xlink': "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink",
        'width': "24",
        'height': "24",
        'x': "0px",
        'y': "0px",
        'viewBox': "0 0 512 512",
        'style': "enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;",
        'xml:space': "preserve"
      }),

      $g1 = makeSVG('g', {
        'id': 'g1'
      }),
      $g1path = makeSVG('g', {
        'id': 'g1path'
      }),
      $path1 = makeSVG('path', {
        'd': 'M346,0c-5.522,0-10,4.478-10,10v46c0,5.522,4.478,10,10,10c5.522,0,10-4.478,10-10V10C356,4.478,351.522,0,346,0z'
      }),

      $g2 = makeSVG('g', {
        'id': 'g2'
      }),
      $g2path = makeSVG('g', {
        'id': 'g2path'
      }),
      $path2 = makeSVG('path', {
        'd': 'M116,312c-5.52,0-10,4.48-10,10c0,5.52,4.48,10,10,10s10-4.48,10-10C124,316.48,121.52,312,116,312z'
      }),

      $g3 = makeSVG('g', {
        'id': 'g3'
      }),
      $g3path = makeSVG('g', {
        'id': 'g3path'
      }),
      $path3 = makeSVG('path', {
        'd': 'M486,292c0-22.056-17.944-40-40-40h-74.652c11.557-29.603,16.235-64.447,15.333-95.464c-0.172-5.919-0.399-9.342-0.706-11.497C385.458,123.432,367.716,106,346,106c-22.056,0-40,17.944-40,40v10c0,63.246-81.214,98.781-142.504,114.019C158.862,259.425,148.284,252,136,252H36c-5.522,0-10,4.478-10,10v240c0,5.522,4.478,10,10,10h100c12.202,0,22.719-7.327,27.401-17.809c5.075,1.302,9.786,2.532,14.135,3.668C212.451,506.978,231.684,512,278.46,512H386c22.056,0,40-17.944,40-40c0-8.224-2.497-15.874-6.77-22.238C434.678,444.359,446,429.599,446,412c0-8.194-2.436-15.869-6.696-22.242C454.684,384.324,466,369.6,466,352c0-8.224-2.497-15.874-6.77-22.238C474.678,324.359,486,309.599,486,292z M146,482c0,5.514-4.486,10-10,10H46V272h90c5.514,0,10,4.486,10,10V482z M446,312c-21.449,0-24.562,0-50,0c-5.522,0-10,4.478-10,10c0,5.522,4.478,10,10,10h30c11.028,0,20,8.972,20,20c0,11.046-8.954,20-20,20h-50c-5.522,0-10,4.478-10,10c0,5.522,4.478,10,10,10h30c10.897,0,20,8.705,20,20c0,11.046-8.954,20-20,20c-21.449,0-24.562,0-50,0c-5.522,0-10,4.478-10,10c0,5.522,4.478,10,10,10h30c11.028,0,20,8.972,20,20s-8.972,20-20,20H278.46c-44.207,0-61.473-4.509-95.87-13.492c-5.039-1.316-10.566-2.759-16.59-4.295V290.025C238.368,272.787,324,230.711,324,156v-10c0-11.028,8.972-20,20-20c11.008,0,19.979,8.958,20,19.969V146c0,4.346,5.424,57.683-16.324,106H316c-5.522,0-10,4.478-10,10c0,5.522,4.478,10,10,10c6.983,0,118.602,0,130,0c11.028,0,20,8.972,20,20C466,303.046,457.046,312,446,312z'
      }),




      $g4 = makeSVG('g', {
        'id': 'g4'
      }),
      $g4path = makeSVG('g', {
        'id': 'g4path'
      }),
      $path4 = makeSVG('path', {
        'd': 'M116,352c-5.522,0-10,4.478-10,10v80c0,5.522,4.478,10,10,10c5.522,0,10-4.478,10-10v-80C124,356.478,121.522,352,116,352z'
      }),

      $g5 = makeSVG('g', {
        'id': 'g5'
      }),
      $g5path = makeSVG('g', {
        'id': 'g5path'
      }),
      $path5 = makeSVG('path', {
        'd': 'M246,124h-40c-5.522,0-10,4.478-10,10c0,5.522,4.478,10,10,10h40c5.522,0,10-4.478,10-10C276,130.478,271.522,124,246,124z'
      }),

      $g6 = makeSVG('g', {
        'id': 'g6'
      }),
      $g6path = makeSVG('g', {
        'id': 'g6path'
      }),
      $path6 = makeSVG('path', {
        'd': 'M466,124h-40c-5.522,0-10,4.478-10,10c0,5.522,4.478,10,10,10h40c5.522,0,10-4.478,10-10C476,130.478,471.522,124,466,124z'
      }),


      $g7 = makeSVG('g', {
        'id': 'g7'
      }),
      $g7path = makeSVG('g', {
        'id': 'g7path'
      }),
      $path7 = makeSVG('path', {
        'd': 'M437.921,44.079c-3.906-3.904-10.236-3.904-14.143,0l-28.279,28.279c-3.905,3.905-3.905,10.237,0,14.143c3.907,3.905,10.236,3.904,14.143,0l28.279-28.279C441.824,54.317,441.824,47.985,437.921,44.079z'
      }),


      $g8 = makeSVG('g', {
        'id': 'g8'
      }),
      $g8path = makeSVG('g', {
        'id': 'g8path'
      }),
      $path8 = makeSVG('path', {
        'd': 'M296.501,72.358l-28.279-28.279c-3.906-3.904-10.236-3.904-14.143,0c-3.905,3.905-3.905,10.237,0,14.143l28.279,28.279c3.908,3.905,10.237,3.904,14.143,0C300.406,82.596,300.406,76.244,296.501,72.358z'
      }),

      $divsapce1 = $("<div>").attr({
        'class': 'p-2',
        id: 'space1'
      }),

      $svgCapa2 = makeSVG('svg', {
        'enable-background': "new 0 0 512.54 512.54",
        'height': "24",
        'viewBox': "0 0 512.54 512.54",
        'width': "24",
        'xmlns': "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
        'id': 'Capa2'
      }),

      $pathcapa20 = makeSVG('path', {
        'd': 'm450.27 379.542h-29.536v-30.009c0-5.523-4.477-10-10-10s-10 4.477-10 10v30.009h-29.536c-5.523 0-10 4.477-10 10s4.477 10 10 10h29.536v30.009c0 5.523 4.477 10 10 10s10-4.477 10-10v-30.009h29.536c5.523 0 10-4.477 10-10s-4.477-10-10-10z'
      }),


      $pathcapa21 = makeSVG('path', {
        'd': 'm482.151 318.124c-19.077-19.077-44.44-29.583-71.418-29.583-13.63 0-24.847 2.686-39.05 7.799v-176.7c0-7.314-2.848-14.191-8.019-19.361l-92.25-92.241c-2.159-2.159-4.673-3.922-7.399-5.244-.003-.002-.007-.003-.01-.005-.128-.062-.256-.125-.385-.186-.238-.116-.479-.224-.727-.321-3.407-1.469-7.106-2.242-10.849-2.242h-222.25c-15.958 0-28.94 12.982-28.94 28.94v454.66c0 15.958 12.982 28.94 28.94 28.94h312.95c15.279 0 27.97-11.946 28.892-27.197.012-.201.018-.402.018-.603v-2.072c12.467 5.213 25.772 7.824 39.08 7.824 25.864 0 51.728-9.845 71.418-29.535 39.379-39.379 39.379-103.456-.001-142.835zm-144.609-215.685h-66.082c-1.22 0-2.212-.993-2.212-2.213v-66.089zm14.111 381.944c-.404 4.594-4.271 8.157-8.91 8.157h-312.949c-4.93 0-8.94-4.01-8.94-8.94v-454.66c0-4.93 4.01-8.94 8.94-8.94h219.454v80.224c0 12.248 9.964 22.213 22.212 22.213h80.224v185.143c-4.355 3.151-8.493 6.666-12.368 10.541-39.38 39.38-39.38 103.456 0 142.836 3.887 3.887 8.017 7.384 12.338 10.503v12.921zm116.356-37.566c-31.581 31.582-82.97 31.582-114.551 0-31.582-31.582-31.582-82.969 0-114.551 15.299-15.299 35.64-23.724 57.275-23.724s41.977 8.425 57.275 23.724c31.583 31.582 31.583 82.969.001 114.551z'
      }),

      $pathcapa22 = makeSVG('path', {
        'd': 'm71.32 159.38h139.414c5.523 0 10-4.477 10-10s-4.477-10-10-10h-139.414c-5.523 0-10 4.477-10 10s4.477 10 10 10z'
      }),

      $pathcapa23 = makeSVG('path', {
        'd': 'm245.505 319.298h-174.185c-5.523 0-10 4.477-10 10s4.477 10 10 10h174.185c5.523 0 10-4.477 10-10s-4.477-10-10-10z'
      }),


      $pathcapa24 = makeSVG('path', {
        'd': 'm245.505 379.271h-174.185c-5.523 0-10 4.477-10 10s4.477 10 10 10h174.185c5.523 0 10-4.477 10-10s-4.477-10-10-10z'
      }),

      $pathcapa25 = makeSVG('path', {
        'd': 'm301.734 259.324h-230.414c-5.523 0-10 4.477-10 10s4.477 10 10 10h230.414c5.523 0 10-4.477 10-10s-4.478-10-10-10z'
      }),


      $pathcapa26 = makeSVG('path', {
        'd': 'm70.32 220h180.414c5.523 0 10-4.477 10-10s-4.477-10-10-10h-180.414c-5.523 0-10 4.477-10 10s4.477 10 10 10z'
      }),

      $circle = makeSVG('circle', {
        cx: "300.5",
        cy: "210",
        r: "10.005"
      }),
      $divspace2 = $("<div>").attr({
        'id': "space2",
        'class': "p-2"
      }),

      $svgCapa3 = makeSVG('svg', {
        'id': "Capa3",
        'xmlns': "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
        'xmlns:xlink': "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink",
        'version': "1.1",
        'x': "0px",
        'y': "0px",
        'viewBox': "0 0 58 58",
        'style': "enable-background:new 0 0 58 58;",
        'xml:space': "preserve",
        'width': "24",
        'height': "24"
      }),

      $gcapa1 = makeSVG('g', {
        'id': 'gcapa1'
      }),
      $gcapapath = makeSVG('g', {
        'id': 'gcapapath'
      }),
      $pathxy1 = makeSVG('path', {
        'd': 'M54.319,37.839C54.762,35.918,55,33.96,55,32c0-9.095-4.631-17.377-12.389-22.153c-0.473-0.29-1.087-0.143-1.376,0.327   c-0.29,0.471-0.143,1.086,0.327,1.376C48.724,15.96,53,23.604,53,32c0,1.724-0.2,3.451-0.573,5.147C51.966,37.051,51.489,37,51,37   c-3.86,0-7,3.141-7,7s3.14,7,7,7s7-3.141,7-7C58,41.341,56.509,39.024,54.319,37.839z M51,49c-2.757,0-5-2.243-5-5s2.243-5,5-5   s5,2.243,5,5S53.757,49,51,49z',
        'data-original': '#000000',
        'class': "active-path",
        'data-old_color': "#000000",
        'fill': "#151313"
      }),

      $pathxy2 = makeSVG('path', {
        'd': 'M38.171,54.182C35.256,55.388,32.171,56,29,56c-6.385,0-12.527-2.575-17.017-7.092C13.229,47.643,14,45.911,14,44   c0-3.859-3.14-7-7-7s-7,3.141-7,7s3.14,7,7,7c1.224,0,2.378-0.319,3.381-0.875C15.24,55.136,21.994,58,29,58   c3.435,0,6.778-0.663,9.936-1.971c0.51-0.211,0.753-0.796,0.542-1.307C39.247,54.213,38.681,53.971,38.171,54.182z M2,44   c0-2.757,2.243-5,5-5s5,2.243,5,5s-2.243,5-5,5S2,46.757,2,44z',
        'data-original': "#000000",
        'class': "active-path",
        'data-old_color': "#000000",
        'fill': "#151313"
      }),


      $pathxy3 = makeSVG('path', {
        'd': 'M4,31.213c0.024,0.002,0.048,0.003,0.071,0.003c0.521,0,0.959-0.402,0.997-0.93c0.712-10.089,7.586-18.52,17.22-21.314   C23.142,11.874,25.825,14,29,14c3.86,0,7-3.141,7-7s-3.14-7-7-7c-3.851,0-6.985,3.127-6.999,6.975   C11.42,9.922,3.851,19.12,3.073,30.146C3.034,30.696,3.449,31.175,4,31.213z M29,2c2.757,0,5,2.243,5,5s-2.243,5-5,5s-5-2.243-5-5   S24.243,2,29,2z',
        'data-original': "#000000",
        'class': "active-path",
        'data-old_color': "#000000",
        'fill': "#151313"
      });

    function makeSVG(tag, attrs) {
      var el = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', tag);
      for (var k in attrs)
        el.setAttribute(k, attrs[k]);
      return $(el);
    }
    $imglinktag1 = $("<a>").attr({
        'href': link,
        'style': 'text-decoration:none',
        'target': '_blank'
      }),
      $imglinktag2 = $("<a>").attr({
        'href': link,
        'style': 'text-decoration:none',
        'target': '_blank'
      });

    // $("#rowview").append($divitem.append($divthumb.append([$divimg.append($imggrp), $divcaption.append([$headcard, $paracard, $divrow.append([$divfooter1.append($lead), $divfooter2.append($atag)])])])));

    if (i < 3) {
      $("#politicsrowviewtop").append($divitem.append($divthumb.append([$divcardheader.append([$divp21.append($imgthumb), $divp22.append($pnewsname), $divmrauto.append($button)]), $imglinktag1.append($divimg.append($imggrp)), $divcaption.append([$imglinktag2.append($headcard), $imglinktag2.append($paracard), $divflex.append([$divtime.append($small), $divsvg.append($svgcapa_1.append([$g1.append($g1path.append($path1)), $g2.append($g2path.append($path2)), $g3.append($g3path.append($path3)), $g4.append($g4path.append($path4)), $g5.append($g5path.append($path5)), $g6.append($g6path.append($path6)), $g7.append($g7path.append($path7)), $g8.append($g8path.append($path8))])), $divsapce1.append($svgCapa2.append([$pathcapa20, $pathcapa21, $pathcapa22, $pathcapa23, $pathcapa24, $pathcapa25, $pathcapa26, $circle])), $divspace2.append($svgCapa3.append($gcapa1.append($gcapapath.append([$pathxy1, $pathxy2, $pathxy3]))))])])])));
    } else {
      $("#politicsrowview").append($divitem.append($divthumb.append([$divcardheader.append([$divp21.append($imgthumb), $divp22.append($pnewsname), $divmrauto.append($button)]), $imglinktag1.append($divimg.append($imggrp)), $divcaption.append([$imglinktag2.append($headcard), $imglinktag2.append($paracard), $divflex.append([$divtime.append($small), $divsvg.append($svgcapa_1.append([$g1.append($g1path.append($path1)), $g2.append($g2path.append($path2)), $g3.append($g3path.append($path3)), $g4.append($g4path.append($path4)), $g5.append($g5path.append($path5)), $g6.append($g6path.append($path6)), $g7.append($g7path.append($path7)), $g8.append($g8path.append($path8))])), $divsapce1.append($svgCapa2.append([$pathcapa20, $pathcapa21, $pathcapa22, $pathcapa23, $pathcapa24, $pathcapa25, $pathcapa26, $circle])), $divspace2.append($svgCapa3.append($gcapa1.append($gcapapath.append([$pathxy1, $pathxy2, $pathxy3]))))])])])));

    }
    shuffle();
  }

});
```

Comment: `which is not working` - console errors? What? Please post examples of flikfeedpoliticsjs.js for example

Comment: you are running this on `$(document).ready()` try running it outside the `$(document).ready()`

Comment: (Removed "eval" my mistake)The javascripts file are not getting added to head when i click on navbar links, and are not executed, there are no console errors @mplungjan

Comment: @RamondeVries   not working even after removing $(document).ready()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19737116/9496199 take a look here

Comment: This post appends using plain or jquery: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413737/how-to-append-script-script-in-javascript there is something you are not telling us - please show `flikfeedpoliticsjs.js`

Comment: @mplungjan it(flikfeedpoliticsjs.js) contains ajax requests to various news websites

Comment: @FaraazHamza We still have no idea what "does not work" means!!!

Comment: @mplungjan the scripts being added to head file(dynamically) is not executing after it is being added. Also not showing in inspect section of browser

Comment: @mplungjan for example whenever i click navbar item "Politics" in html file, the JS file "flikfeedpoliticsjs.js" should be added to head section,  and should execute.Therefore the ajax call present inside flikfeedpoliticsjs.js file should execute. This execution is not happening.

Comment: Does it appear in the network tab when you click the link in the page to load it?

Comment: @mplungjan no its not appearing in network tab(its not getting added)

Comment: Hmm, weird. I will look again

Comment: @mplungjan if u didnt get my question plz tell me i will again reframe the question in neat way

Comment: i will update the question again if u it looks unorganized @mplungjan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is that you have a # in your ID attributes so all your `.is()`  fail

Your use of the event target is suspicious and unnecessary anyway

This should work better

I would also remove `$(document).ready(function(){ })` from the loaded scripts

```js
$(function() {
  $(".navbar-nav").on('click', '.nav-item', function() {
    var $techscript = $("<script>",{
      "type": 'text/javascript',
      src: '/js/' + $(this).data("js")
    });
    console.log($techscript.attr("src"))
    $('head').prepend($techscript)
  })
  $("[href='#foryoupage']").click(); // load the first links onload
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="navbar-nav">
    <a href="#foryoupage" class="nav-item nav-link active" data-js="flikfeedjs.js">For You</a>
    <div></div>
    <a href="#techpage" class="nav-item nav-link hello " data-js="flikfeedtech.js">Technology</a>
    <div></div>
    <a href="#politicspage" class="nav-item nav-link hello" data-js="flikfeedpoliticsjs.js">Politics</a>
    <div></div>
    <a href="#movtvpage" class="nav-item nav-link hello" data-js="flikfeedmoviesjs">Movies/Tv shows</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: ur code worked thank you very much for being with me for such long hours.

Comment: You are welcome. It was actually just a typo, but the code I gave you is simpler and easier to maintain

Comment: Can i tag u again if i have doubts on this project again, well there are many more questions i have

Answer (score -1):

since you're using jquery, you can use the `getScript()` function: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript

UPDATE:  I ran your code and it looks like it's failing when you get to the first condition: `if ($(ev1.target).is("#foryoupage")) {`

all of your conditions return `false`, so i'd investigate that.

Comment: Yes you CAN append a JS file to the HEAD and it will run

Comment: @mplungjan okay..... but you didnt read the first part of my answer. the eval part was only an  "fyi" ... his original code wasn't even  reaching `eval`. his issue in his code is in his conditions. `console.log($(ev1.target))`

Comment: your answer doesn't answer  his  issue  at all. you've removed his conditions.

Comment: I removed my downvote - the error is the # in his IDs

Comment: @mplungjan im merely matching the tone you've held throughout this entire exchange. but you've deleted your comments, so...

Comment: I am often failing to see why terseness is seen as arrogant. My (not deleted) comment was "Yes you CAN append a JS file to the HEAD and it will run" no emotional content there. Apologies if that came across as arrogant

Comment: i was referring to the one after that about my updated comment, but no problem.

Comment: `all of your conditions return false, so i'd investigate that.` is not an answer either by the way - it would be a comment at best according to SO's guidelines