# Assuring a callback for an async script

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous

I have to load a third party script that is not critical for displaying the body (say for simplicity that it adds a red background on ".red" divs).

```
<script src="redify.js" async defer></script>
```

I need to execute `function myRedify(){ $(".red").redify(); }` after the script is loaded.

The script is huge and takes long time (say 3 seconds) to load, but once finished I need to see my `.red` divs became red.

```
<script src="redify.js" async defer onload="myRedify()"></script>
```

Is that the recommended way to do it?

**Remarks**

- `redify.js` is a third party script that I can't modify
- I don't mind if the divs became red not immediately, but after a delay(when the script is loading, 3 seconds - ok)

Comment: After the script is loaded it is _immediately_ executed, so you can place `myPostFunction()` at the end of the script.

Comment: @r3wt, OP is asking recommended way!

Comment: to be fair, he asked if this is the recommended way and not if this is possible with the code above :)

Comment: @ins0 this is the only possible way unless you create the script programattically in javascript and do `script.onload = function(){...`, or as @Halcyon said just call your function at the bottom of the script.

Comment: i wasn't asking, but thanks anyway ^^. why not post it as an answer?

Comment: Is this script dynamically inserted? If not and its just in the HTML why make it async?

Comment: another possible way would be with a jsonP callback. in the querystring.

Comment: If you have a script B that relies on script A, don't make script A async. That will be inviting trouble. Always load them in a synchronous fashion.

Comment: This kind a question is already answered in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644558/call-javascript-function-after-script-is-loaded)

Comment: @Halcyon please see the updated remark

Comment: Thanks mmcorrelo - ugly solution - valuable!

Comment: Where is `myPostFunction()` defined?

Comment: please see my updates to clarify the question

Comment: Why do you have `async` and `defer`? It is ok for the page to initially load un-redified?

Comment: @Halcyon please see the remarks. Initially the div has no color, then after the script loading becames red

Comment: please note, using `defer` here does nothing. as stated in the [docs for defer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer): "*This attribute must not be used if the src attribute is absent*"

Answer (score 0):

Your approach works, and by that it has merrit. Is it recommended? Maybe.
Your approach has some advantages and some disadvantages:

- performance: loading of the redify script starts immediately
- readability: just looking at the HTML it's pretty obvious what's going on
- the disadvantage is that, if you were to add another library (for example: `blueify.js`) you have to duplicate the mechanism.

Right now your code is tightly coupled through the `myRedify` function. You can decouple it by building a simple `require` strategy:

```
var libraries = {
    redify: "redify.js",
    blueify: "blueify.js"
};
var lib_bookkeep = {};

function require(library_name, callback) {
    if (lib_bookkeep[library_name]) {
         if (lib_bookkeep[library_name].status === "loaded") {
             callback();
         } else {
             lib_bookkeep[library_name].elem.addEventListener("load", callback);
         }
    } else {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = libraries[library_name];
        script.addEventListener("load", function () {
            lib_bookkeep[library_name].status = "loaded";
        });
        script.addEventListener("load", callback);
        document.head.appendChild(script);
        lib_bookkeep[library_name] = {
            elem: script
            status: "loading"
        }
    }
}

require("redify", function () {
    $(".red").redify();
});

require("redify", function () {
    $(".also-red").redify();
});

require("blueify", function () {
    $(".blue").redify();
});
require("blueify", function () {
    require("redify", function () {
        $(".purple").redify().blueify();
    });
});
```

This allows you to expand on the libraries that you have, and it allows you to use them arbitrarily. This would by the approach that I recommend. If however you just have this once instance, it's probably find to do it like you have, with `asynch/defer` and `onload`.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "add a script include and call any callbacks once it's loaded" is it an ajax call?

Comment: @Serge I added a sample implementation. I haven't tested it but it should work in theory.