# image not showing after adding it dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this script 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="customJS/jsonRetrieve.js" async></script>`

The script makes me retrieve the data from a JSON file and store it in an array.

first question is: how can i load my index page only after the script is fully loaded? i get the error of 'undefined'.

After loading the script i have to add the code from the array something like this

```
"<img src='images2/1.jpg' id='0' style='width:70%' class='rounded' data-toggle='modal' onclick='setMod(this.id);setData(this.id)' data-target='#myModal' />"
```

to my carousel and that by adding it to the div. I used the jQuery function 'append' to add the images to my #carousel div but the images are not showing in the carousel preview. how can i fix that ? should i refresh the carousel ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.waterwheelCarousel.js" defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="customJS/carouselJS.js" defer></script>

$(window).load(function () {
      $('#carousel').append(items[0]);
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal verifiable example with a working snippet?

Comment: You would ideally need to refresh the carousel after adding the images dynamically.

Comment: @Studocwho how can i refresh the carousel scripts and css and the div

Comment: @CalvinNunes thats alot of work x)

Comment: cant i make the carousel to load only after i added the images dynamically ?

Comment: I don't know what carousel you are using, but go over the documentation for it, there should typically be some kind of refreshing method you could use.

Comment: @Studocwho okayy. how about preventing the script from loading until i add the images ?

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent a script from loading until you add the images with something like this:

`<script onload="customJsFunction();" src ="customJS/jsonRetrieve.js"></script>`

A similar question is here: [Call javascript function after script is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644558/call-javascript-function-after-script-is-loaded).

Comment: Could you you setup a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ It'll help everyone read and test your code.

Comment: i think i have to load this script <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.waterwheelCarousel.js" ></script> after i add the images

Comment: any solution ?  i couldnt find a way to make this work

Comment: Thanks for making a fiddle. The issue is with `$('#carousel').append(items[0]);`. items isn't an array defined in that function! You need to return the value of `jsonRetrieve.js` not just include the file.

Please check out line 43 https://jsfiddle.net/j4pruxs5/1/