# Js head Append script

Tags: javascript, html

While appending a script tag programmatically after the head element,

```
head.appendChild(script_elm);
```

within this above script element, i am defining a variable. If i want to access the variable which is defining within the script tag, it does not work immediately after the head append. Why?

Comment: If you are loading an external JavaScript file you must wait it to be fully loaded before accessing to variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call javascript function after script is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644558/call-javascript-function-after-script-is-loaded)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wait for the script to be loaded. as @DanieleAlessandra comments

```
 script_elem.onload = function() {
      // some code
    };
```

see this question

[Call javascript function after script is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644558/call-javascript-function-after-script-is-loaded)

Comment: Personally I would never "wait" for a single piece of script to load a single variable. I would suggest either using an `ajax` call to request the variable, or use a `serversided preprocessor` (like PHP) or simply include the script in the `head` and wait for the `DOMContentLoaded` event.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to make access to that variable available through your script.
For example, `external-script.js`

```
window.externalScript = function () {

    const yourVariable = //do some magic here;
    this.scriptVariable = yourVariable;
    // your code
}
```

Then you can use this variable in your onload function like so:

```
script_elem.onload = () => {
    if (window.externalScript &&
        window.externalScript().scriptVariable) {
        //do whatever you want to do with your script variable.
    }
}
```