# Loading sequence of scripts in html

Tags: javascript, html

I want to load a constants file as per the language the user has selected. For that I want to load the scripts dynamically.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var jsElement = document.createElement("script");
      jsElement.type = "application/javascript";
      jsElement.src = "../constants.en.js";
      document.body.appendChild(jsElement);
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/RandomScript.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Whole code is in HTML.

When I tried the code above, `RandomScript.js` is loaded before the constant file.

How can I maintain sequence of loading files.

I am not using jQuery or something, so is there any way to do interpolation of `src` of script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call javascript function after script is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644558/call-javascript-function-after-script-is-loaded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `onload` event listener to load `.js` files sequentially.

First create an array of URLs of scripts. Then loop through it recursively. `onload` event listener ensures that the scripts are loaded sequentially.

```
var scriptURLs = [
   "../constants.en.js",
   "../js/RandomScript.js"
];

function loadScript(index){
  if(index >= scriptURLs.length){
    return false;
  }

  var el = document.createElement('script');
  el.onload = function(){
    console.log("Script loaded: ", scriptURLs[index]);
    loadScript(index+1);
  }
  el.src = scriptURLs[index];
  document.body.appendChild(el);
  // OR
  // document.head.appendChild(el);
}

loadScript(0); // Load the first script manually.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: what if there are so many script loaded directly like randomScript. should I make array of all script's src and load this way?

Comment: If you want to load the other scripts in a specific order, with this approach the only thing you need is to add the URL in the array with the order. But if you don't mind the loading order, you can load them directly.

Comment: @CHIRAGBAVISHI Usually I don't prefer to do this but since you're a new contributor, I would like to ask you to upvote and mark the answer as accepted. This way the future readers will have a chance to quickly find the answer for their own questions. Have a nice day.

Comment: but ajax calling before file is loading, as there so many files

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't quite get it. Can you provide an example of the use cases somewhere like plunker or stackblitz?

Comment: I have there are some ajax call in main page, if we load scripts dynamically then those ajax called after some script loaded even though ajax call is after the loading script dynamic.

Comment: cant't I load script like <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/FileName_{{here variable }}"></script>
to load script dyanmically?

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsElement = document.createElement("script");
jsElement.type = "application/javascript";
document.body.appendChild(jsElement);

jsElement.onload = () => {
    callyournewScript();
}

jsElement.src = "../constants.en.js";
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Load the `../js/RandomScript.js` after loading the `../constants.en.js` like following

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var jsElement = document.createElement("script");
      jsElement.type = "application/javascript";
      jsElement.src = "../constants.en.js";
      document.body.appendChild(jsElement);

      var script = document.createElement("script");
      script.src = "../js/RandomScript.js";
      script.type = "text/javascript";
      document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

    </script>
  <!--  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/RandomScript.js"></script> -->
</body>
```

Comment: What if `constants.en.js` is a bigger file than `RandomScript.js`? It will load later if it is bigger. This does not ensure loading order.

Comment: what if there are so many script added like RandomScript.js file. Should I go load this way for all?