# Clarification for appendChild

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I added a Cookies Consent banner. The requirement is that `https://cdn.cookielaw.org/consent/c4337328/OtAutoBlock.js` loaded before any other script. I now wonder if `appendChild` is the right choice. Will it load `OtAutoBlock` at the exact position I wrote it or will it append the script to the end of the  tag (which would be too late). It has to be the first script that's loaded.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- OneTrust Cookies Consent Notice -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      if ("%REACT_APP_COOKIE_BAR%" === "true") {
        var otAutoBlock = document.createElement("script");
        otAutoBlock.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        otAutoBlock.setAttribute("src", "https://cdn.cookielaw.org/consent/c4337328/OtAutoBlock.js");
        
        var otSDKStub = document.createElement("script");
        otSDKStub.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        otSDKStub.setAttribute("src", "https://cdn.cookielaw.org/scripttemplates/otSDKStub.js");
        otSDKStub.setAttribute("charset", "UTF-8");
        otSDKStub.setAttribute("data-domain-script", "c4337328");

        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(otAutoBlock);
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(otSDKStub);

        function OptanonWrapper() { }
      }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      /* [Should load after OtAutoBlock loads to avoid tracking before consent was given] */
    </script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can simply hard code the ùrl in the script tag knw.

Comment: Why can't you load the script with a `<script src="">` tag?

Comment: @LuisAFK I chose that way as I need to check the following first: `if ("%REACT_APP_COOKIE_BAR%" === "true")`

Comment: @JoeyCoder this might be helpful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644558/call-javascript-function-after-script-is-loaded

Comment: @JoeyCoder can't you control that in server side, like PHP, since it can access and set cookies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.head.appendChild(script)` will add it to the end of the `<head>` tag, so it will load after all other scripts. You can do two things:

1. You load it with `appendChild` at the end, and have all your other scripts with a `defer` attribute, like this: `<script defer> /* something */ </script>` The `defer` forces a script to execute after the page is loaded, but if you load the `OtAutoBlock` without a `defer`, it will run before the others. The only thing to note is that `defer` will cause the scripts not to run last, but after the *entire page* loads, which includes CSS stylesheets, other JavaScripts, icons, images, HTML content, XHR requests in `<script>` tags, etc.

```html
<script>
const load = true; // your stuff here

if (load)
{
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  
  window.hasRunned = false;
  script.text = 'alert(\'OtAutoBlock running.\'); window.hasRunned = true;';
  
  document.head.appendChild(script);
}
</script>

<script defer>
alert('Another script. Has runned OtAutoBlock: ' + window.hasRunned);
</script>

<script defer>
alert('And yet another. Has runned OtAutoBlock: ' + window.hasRunned);
</script>
```

2. You use `insertBefore` to add it before the other scripts, so it will run before them. No need to use `defer` with this method. This might be what you want if you need the scripts to run *before* the page loads.

```html
<script>
const load = true; // your stuff here

if (load)
{
  let script = document.createElement('script');
  
  window.hasRunned = false;
  script.text = 'alert(\'OtAutoBlock running.\'); window.hasRunned = true;';
  
  document.head.insertBefore(script, document.head.children[0]);
}
</script>

<script>
alert('Another script. Has runned OtAutoBlock: ' + window.hasRunned);
</script>

<script>
alert('And yet another. Has runned OtAutoBlock: ' + window.hasRunned);
</script>
```

Comment: That's very helpful. Thank you @LuisAFK