# How to check if script done running

Tags: javascript

I'm injecting programmatically some text-code into script, and I need to run some code only **after** the script is done running.

My code:

```
const InjectScript = (scriptContent) => {
  const script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.text = scriptContent;
  document.head.appendChild(script);

 //run some code after script executed
   someCode()
};
```

How can I check if the script is done running?

Comment: By the time `someCode()` runs your dynamically inserted javascript will already have executed (except any async code in it).

Comment: Use promises in JavaScript it is what you are looking for see [MDN guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: @Sanmeet Nothing async in the question, so no use for promises.

Comment: @connexo I think the OP is looking for something async as it the above code doesn't needs anything more !

Comment: Why do you even add a script tag with custom content instead of just running the code directly? (or is this a content script in a browser extension?)

Comment: Fire an event from the dynamic script that `someCode` listens for.

Comment: Set a global variable that `someCode`  checks for.

Comment: Please add information if the inserted script runs async code that you need to wait for.

Comment: Attach to `window.someCode` then pass the name of the function to your dynamic script with `data-` attributes.

Comment: Use `MutationObserver` and have `someCode` `observe` a node the dynamic script modifies.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/14644704/258174

Answer (score -1):

I think as like this

```
  var IsRunning = false;
  function myFunction() {
   if (!IsRunning) {
    IsRunning = true;
    }
    }
```

Comment: This is either not needed (if the inserted JS is not async), or useless (if it is). Aside from  the fact that it is making use of global variables (which is generally frowned upon).

Answer (score -1):

async await seems like the best choice if your runtime is okay with ECMAScript 2017 syntax, like so:

```
const InjectScript = async (scriptContent) => {
  const script = await document.createElement("script");
  script.type = await "text/javascript";
  script.text = await scriptContent;
  await document.head.appendChild(script);

  //run some code after script executed
  await someCode()
};
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: `appendChild` is not async so cannot be awaited, probably neither is `someCode` and it would not make a difference to await it anyway.

Comment: await is to ensure it runs in sequence, nothing to do with promises being compulsory. thanks for the feedback anyway

Comment: This does not prevent someCode from executing before the dynamic script finishes.